# Gaps between faces; how can I join them, without filling?

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm new to 3D modeling and wanted to try Blender. I'm following Katsbits animated snowman tutorial and I just noticed there's a "gap" between my snowman and his scarf where it meets his neck and near the bottom of his body.[image: Visible gaps between body and scarf]I don't think this was there before, I must have done something to create this gap by mistake. I want to join the scarf to meet the bottom of his neck, but without creating a new face. I used "snap during transform" to bring the edges together, which appeared to do what I wanted, but if I move the vertexes of either the scarf or the snowman I can see that they still aren't connected. How do I fix this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seect the vertices you want to merge and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to bring up the Merge menu and select 'At Center'. Repeat for each set of vertices you want to merge.

Alternatively, if the vertices are close enough, you can select them all and use Remove Doubles (on the Mesh/Vertices menu) - increase the Merge Distance in the left-hand panel until those vertices merge together.